# How to avoid answer papers being flappy under a fan?

Tags: stationery, office-supplies, air, fan

During my examination time, the answer papers are supposed to flappy due to ceiling fan. I have things to put weight on such as watch, kerchief, extra pens, eraser etc., But is there any other way to stop papers being flappy under a fan.

Don't suggest me things like, to switch off fan, use paper weight etc.,

Comment: I got frustrated on searching a suitable tag. Sorry for wrong tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because it doesn't seem to need a life hack. It's a physical event when the papers under a fan are flappy. I don't believe there's another method to prevent this, other than placing something on the paper. You could possibly construct something right under the fan that would redirect the air flow, but then it would not fulfill the purpose of cooling you down.

Answer (score 4):

If there are multiple answer pages, you can clip them together with paper clips, binder clips, or bulldog clips. Being bound to each other, that will limit how much they can flap around in the breeze.

[image][image][image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer @BrettFromLA, but my country's exam regulation doesn't allow clips to bring in.

Answer (score 3):

We can control the flying(flapping)   papers by inserting a pen cap like a paperclip on a couple of papers together. This will probably makes papers difficult to flap. Hope we have some additional pens to use for.

Comment: You could dog ear the pages. That would work like a clip, I would think.

Answer (score 2):

You can drastically reduce the flapping of the papers by using at least two foot rulers on each sheet. Place them at the 2 long edges of the sheet. Being flat, they shouldn't interfere with your writing, and being stationary, they should be allowed during your examinations.

Comment: Metal rulers would work extrawell